# Setting up Eclipse and Java JDK

Tags: android, eclipse, java, java-6

I've been attempting to install and set up the Java JDK 1.6 and Eclipse (helios) on Windows 7.

I have downloaded the 32 bit of each, as the 64 bit Eclipse version didn't want to work.

So, having done that and amended the eclipse.ini file to pick up the right java.exe, I'm getting exit code 13 when running Eclipse.  Have I made an error in the eclipse.ini some place?

Thanks!

-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.0.v20100507.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.1.R36x_v20100810
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
-vm
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_23\jre\bin\java.exe
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xms40m
-Xmx384m

Comment: Are you able to run other java programs? Check which java version is used by typing "java -version" and then "where java" to know where java executables are.

Comment: Thanks - Java is working and recognised by other programs.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you should be pointing to javaw.exe http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini

-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
-vm
C:\Java\JDK\1.5\bin\javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m

Comment: I tried that - I should have said.  Sorry.  I get the same result regardless of jave.exe or javew.exe.

Answer (score 0):

```
--launcher.defaultAction openFile
```

appears two times. Maybe try to remove this after the -vm argument

It also seems that you are still referencing a 64bit version:

```
--launcher.library plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.1.R36x_v20100810
```

This is my similar solution using the JDK instead of the JRE.

`-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.0.v20100507.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.1.R36x_v20100810
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
384M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
384m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vm
c:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.6.0_21/bin/javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xms128m
-Xmx1024m`

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Good spot, but not a positive result I'm afraid!

Comment: Added my eclipse.ini and a hint that you are still using 64bit launcher (maybe copied the eclipse.ini from the first 64bit version attempt?). Please check this...

Comment: The relative reference to the library in the .ini appears to be correct.  The reference to the 64 seems correct, as removing it/editing displays an error on startup of Eclipse, basically stating that that the library can't be found.  I'll start over and see how I get on and will post results here.  Thanks all for the help.

Comment: I doubt that it is correct to use the 64bit eclipse (org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.1.R36x_v20100810) with the 32bit Java (Program Files (x86)). I would recommend to start with a fresh unziped eclipse x32 application, backup the original eclipse.ini and make change by change (or even change nothing)

Answer (score 0):

Error 13 is usually a dead giveaway for a 32/64-bit mismaatch, which is evident in using a JRE installed under "C:\Program Files (x86)" (exclusively for 32-bit applications on a 64-bit Windows) and a 64-bit Eclipse (the reference to bundles with the arch x86_64 in their hame).